# Can xquery delete the text xmlns="" from a node

Tags: sql-server, xml

OS: Windows 10

MS SQL Version: SQL 2016

I have searched StackOverflow extensively and found many questions which are very similar to mine, but none seem to match my circumstances or have a response that I have the knowledge or skill to implement. I don't know how to implement a C# solution within SQL, nor do I know how to use stylesheet transformation language, so here is my question.

I am creating an XML document from a table and must have it match my customer's layout exactly. The outer structure of the document looks something like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ScreenResponse xmlns="http://schemas.myuri.com/CC/v1_4">
      <CustomerScreenResult>
       <ServiceCallID />
        <IsSuccessful>true</IsSuccessful>
        <CustomerScreenResponse>
          <IsSuccessful>true</IsSuccessful>
        </CustomerScreenResponse>
      </CustomerScreenResult>
    </ScreenResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The object above is called @xml_out in my stored procedure, has a data type of XML, and remains constant. Please note that it uses only schemas and namespaces and no stylesheets. Next, I build another XML document that displays only the nodes the customer needs to see. It looks like this:

```
<SpecificScreenResults>
  <CaseScreenResult>
    <ScreenMessage>This is a sample screenmessage.</ScreenMessage>
  </CaseScreenResult>
  <CaseScreenResult>
    <ScreenMessage>This is another sample screenmessage.</ScreenMessage>
  </CaseScreenResult>
</SpecificScreenResults>
```

In SSMS, I create that document with code similar to this:

```
SET @xml_var1 = ( SELECT a.ScreenMessage
FROM #CustScrn a 
FOR
XML PATH('CaseScreenResult'),
ELEMENTS,
ROOT ('SpecificScreenResults'),
TYPE);
```

Finally, I use an xquery insert statement to insert the second XML object (@xml_var1) into the first XML object. First, here's the SQL statement that I use:

```
SET @xml_out.modify('declare default element namespace "http://schemas.myuri.com/CC/v1_4"; insert sql:variable ("@xml_var1") as first into (//CustomerScreenResponse)[1]');
```

This yields the following XML object:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ScreenResponse xmlns="http://schemas.myuri.com/CC/v1_4">
      <CustomerScreenResult>
        <ServiceCallID />
        <IsSuccessful>true</IsSuccessful>
        <CustomerScreenResponse>
          <SpecificScreenResults xmlns="">
            <CaseScreenResult>
              <ScreenMessage>This is a sample screenmessage.</ScreenMessage>
            </CaseScreenResult>
            <CaseScreenResult>
              <ScreenMessage>This is another sample creenmessage.</ScreenMessage>
            </CaseScreenResult>
          </SpecificScreenResults>
          <IsSuccessful>true</IsSuccessful>
        </CustomerScreenResponse>
      </CustomerScreenResult>
    </ScreenResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Note the one node, SpecificScreenResults is receiving the extra xmlns="" namespace indication. I think this is happening because the XML I am inserting isn't associated with a namespace, and so a blank one is added. I understand that from an XML standpoint this text is insignificant, but to my customer it is an irritation that they don't want to deal with. Currently the way I handle the issue is to convert the entire object over to VARCHAR(MAX), use a REPLACE() function to remove it, and then convert it back to XML. This works ok for results with a few records but not so well when the table results number in the millions.

Yes or no, is there an xquery delete command I can use to delete the xmlns="" from the node? Is there a better way to perform the insert to prevent the blank from occurring? If so, can someone please provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that from an XML standpoint this text is insignificant,
>   but to my customer it is an irritation that they don't want to deal
>   with.

On the contrary, this little declaration is highly significant.

You created the `<SpecificScreenResults>` element and its descendants in no namespace. When you copy it as a subtree of another document, it remains in no namespace, and the `xmlns=""` declaration is added to reflect this fact.

It seems that you want the `<SpecificScreenResults>` element to be in the namespace `"http://schemas.myuri.com/CC/v1_4"`. If you want it in that namespace, you must either create it in that namespace, or transform it subsequently to change its namespace.

It's important to remember that elements have a name which is a (namespace, local-name) pair, and when you copy an element, its name remains unchanged. Namespace declarations like `xmlns=""` aren't part of the XPath/XQuery data model, they are an artifact of lexical (serialized) XML designed to ensure that when you convert a tree to lexical XML and then parse it back to a tree, the names of the elements remain unchanged. If an element is one namespace and its parent is in a different namespace, then on serialization, namespace declarations will be added to reflect this fact.

Answer (score 0):

This `xmlns=""` is not just annoying, it specifies, that the inner nodes **do not live within the default namespace you declare above!** This is - quite probably, not what you want actually...

You might create the node to insert including `WITH XMLNAMESPACES(...)`. This will create the new node within the same default namespace as the outer nodes. After insertion via `.modify()` you will notice, that you will find your `xmlns="..."` several times. This is not wrong, just annoying and bloating your XML...

This is a long lasting issue. See this [Connect article](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/265956/suppress-namespace-attributes-in-nested-select-for-xml-statements)! Please sign in and vote!

There are several approaches with string methods. Ugly, but working...

> Currently the way I handle the issue is to convert the entire object over to VARCHAR(MAX), use a REPLACE() function to remove it, and then convert it back to XML.

This is okay, but you should use `NVARCHAR`. Using `VARCHAR` could get you into troubles with *non-plain-latin* characters...

Most people would advise to create the XML without any namespace and use `STUFF` to insert all namespaces on string level at the end.